# Disqus - SSO does not work

Tags: disqus

I am using Disqus in my website to help users add comments on certain pages. I have followed the SSO documentation and I also had a look at SSO Checklist. This is what is happening:

User logs in to the website.
User visits page where he can add comments.
(i am using the universal code and I have added public api key and remote_auth_s3 and I can SSO the user in Disqus).
User adds comments.
Second user logs in and adds his comments on the page.
Now Second user sees the first user comments clicks on the user link.
This opens up a popup showing the first user info and the follow button.
On clicking the follow button, it gives me a 401 Unauthorized exception on chrome console.
How can I make "follow" work?

Screen capture link: http://screencast.com/t/utsydcJ8K3QR

Thanks
RP

Answer (score 0):

SSO users have accounts very specific to that website and they can't be used on other communities, so following actually shouldn't be an option. Since there isn't anything wrong with your implementation, please email us here to report it: http://disqus.com/support/

Comment: Thanks for your comment Ryan. But I just want to clarify that I am trying to add two users of the same website (communitiy). I know the popup (profile) is actually a iframe. May be the iframe does not have the authenticated userinfo and thats why I get the 401?